# Как обнулить переменную раз в месяц?

Tags: php

Как обнулить переменную раз в месяц? например 1 числа.

```
    if(date("d")==1;){
    $numberWay = 01;
}
```

но так переменная будет обнулятся весь день. Я думаю в строну cron. Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Где вы храните данные?

Comment: час в условие добавь

Comment: Храню в бд mysql

Comment: если час добавить, то если скрипт запустится после указанного времени, переменная не обновится ((

Comment: Зачем обнулять переменную да еще и раз в месяц? Опиши реальную задачу для которой это нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите сделать что-то раз в месяц.

В БД можно сохранять запись "в 2020-08 сделано", сразу как сделали.

В скрипте смотреть, какой месяц, и если для него всё сделано -- не делать.

Скрипт можно запускать и по cron, с любой частотой.

Главное, чтоб 2 скрипта не сработали одновременно.

Можно сделать демона (проверил-поспал по циклу).

Comment: спасибо))))))))